# Convert epoch number to date and add 01/01/1970 to display the output in HIVE SQL

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying hard to figure out how to convert epoch number (column name: effectivedate and datatype: string, value: 19186 ) to date format as mm/dd/yyyy and add '01/01/1970' to display the output in HIVE SQL.

For example: 19186 + 01/01/1970 should display 07/13/2022 as output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `date_add()`. The column effectivedate doesnt look like number of days from 1/1/1970. So using above function you can easily convert it to a full date.

```
SELECT date_add('1970-01-01', cast(effectivedate as BIGINT))
```

Test SQL  `SELECT date_add('1970-01-01', 19186 )`

[image: Test Result]